# Set Intersection Method and operator overloading

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, operator-overloading

So below I have the following blocks of code. It is a default constructor that also has a default parameter of 10. The next method is a intersection method, that takes the intersection of two set objects. Also, there is an element method that checks an element. The next is a operator overloaded method that is supposed to remove an element from the set. Here are some of the problems I'm experiencing:

-The intersection method is displaying the elements as 0, even though its supposed to display the element that is shared between both sets. For example, when I type in the set {1,2} and another set {2,3,4} it is supposed to display {2}, but it displays 0. Surprisingly, when I checked the size of the set C it is displayed as 1, which is correct.

-The operator-() function is supposed to remove and element, but the delete set[i] is not working

Lastly, I am aware of the variable names im using, but I am using these names to set a better sense of what's going on. Also, we are not allowed to use the set in the standard library

```
Set::Set ( int s ){

        if ( s > 0 )
                psize = s;
        else
                psize = DEFAULTSIZE;
        //allocate an array of specified size
        set = new int[ psize ];

        if(!set) {
                //send an error is system cannot allocate memory
                cout << "Cannot Allocate Memory, exiting program... " << endl;
                exit (1);
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
                set[i] = 0;
                numOfElements = 0;
        }
}
Set Set::operator-( int n ){
        for ( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++){
                if(element(n)){
                        delete set[i];
                        numOfElements--;
                }
        }
        psize = numOfElements;

        return (*this);
}
Set Set::Intersection( Set &B ) {

        int newsize = numOfElements;

        Set C(newsize);
        int indx = 0;
                for ( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++ ){
                        if( B.element(set[i])){
                                C.set[indx] = set[i];
                                indx++;
                        }
                        else{
                                newsize--;
                                continue;
                        }
                }

        C.numOfElements = newsize;

        return C;
}
bool Set::element ( int n ){
        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
                if ( set[i] == n )
                        return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: numOfElements is a placeholder for fillsize (this is what I was required to name it). psize is the physical size of the array

Comment: I don't know what `delete set[i];` means or why you can compile it, since `set` is apparently an `int*`.  Since sequence is generally unimportant in a "set" the usual way to drop an item is to move the physically last overwriting it:  `set[i]=set[--numOfElements];`  But also, the `element(n)` test is unsound, since you need to know whether `set[i]==n` for the current `i`, not just whether it is in there somewhere.

Comment: Also, did you intend an `operator-` or an `operator-=`?  The former should be modifying a copy, not the original.  The later ought to return a `&` not a copy.

Comment: I intended the former based on my instructors specifications. However, I am still unsure about my element function and I don't exactly know how to fix it.

Comment: If `element` is spec'ed to return a `bool` (rather than a type that could be used instead of `bool` but also serves a side purpose), then I don't think it is practical for `operator-` to make use of `element`.  Instead `operator-` should just make a copy of the current object skipping the specified item.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest mistake is the first `i` in

```
C.set[i] = set[i];
```

You are non densely filling C.set, but you later compute its size as if you had densely filled it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! How exactly would I go about fixing it?

Comment: I figured out what you were saying thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Do you by any chance have any insight into how to fix my operator- () function?

Comment: Edit the posted code if you solved a problem but still need more help.  I prefer to see the current version of whatever I'm trying to diagnose.

Comment: I have uploaded the edited code based on your suggestions